# How i can do that?

Tags: java

How can I do a date validation with leap years in Java? Unfortunately, I can't use regular expressions or calendar. I will explain step by step!

This is my main component (where I implement most things):
An example of the implement I have to use:

and in another component called utility (I put the methods that will be used in the implementation, all this to carry an order, my utility code is as follows:

I put the data separately in a LOCAL ENVIRONMENT online, where I put a date that is valid in any respective year. enter image description here

For example in the image, I am putting the date 02/29/2012 which is validated and is in the correct order, but if I put a date 02/30/2012 which is incorrect data, it will throw me an error called 10005.

Comment: Personally, I'd just use [SimpleDateFormat.parse()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).  If the date is invalid, it should return null.  Try it :)

Comment: Please write the description or about the image.

Comment: @paulsm4 Not really: it will throw a `ParseException` (and only if lenient is set to `false`, otherwise a more-or-less appropriate date will be returned) **||** It is recommended NOT to use the legacy `Date`, `Calendar`, `SimpleDaeFormat`... classes; - prefer the `java.time` package ones (but I believe this is an *assignment* and it is not permitted to use any of these classes)

Comment: Can you not use the [date time API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/index.html) ?

Comment: @Abra I think yes! Could you help me how to implement it?

Comment: @Carlos fernando - I encourage you to try SimpleDateFormat().  It might be all you need.  Ignore those who insist "newer is by always better".  Here some good examples: [Creating a SimpleDateFormat](https://jenkov.com/tutorials/java-internationalization/simpledateformat.html) and [A Guide to SimpleDateFormat](https://www.baeldung.com/java-simple-date-format).  You should familiarize yourself with the newer, Java8 [DateTimeFormatter class](https://www.baeldung.com/java-datetimeformatter), but feel free to continue using SimpleDateFormat() if it works for you.

Comment: Terrible title. Rewrite to summarize your *specific* technical issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is my last kick at the cat. No `Calendar`, no `regex`, and no `try/catch`. date range is from the year 1200 to the year 2200 (can be changed in code). The concept is used from **Gilbert Le Blanc's** answer:

```
public boolean isDateStringValid(String dateString) {
    if (dateString == null || dateString.isEmpty()) {
        return false;
    }

    // Maximum days in each month starting from January
    int[] maxDays = {31, 28, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31};

    // Parse the supplied date string
    String m = dateString.substring(0, dateString.indexOf("/"));
    String d = dateString.substring(dateString.indexOf("/") + 1, dateString.lastIndexOf("/"));
    String y = dateString.substring(dateString.lastIndexOf("/") + 1);
    
    
    
    //convert days, month, and year to integer.
    int month = Integer.valueOf(m);
    int day = Integer.valueOf(d);
    int year = Integer.valueOf(y);

    // Make sure year is in range
    if (year < 1200 || year > 2200) {
        return false;
    } 
    
    /* If the year provided is a Leap year then change the Maximum
       days for February (in maxDays[]) from 28 days to 29 days. */
    if ((year % 4 == 0 && year % 100 != 0) || (year % 400 == 0)) {
        maxDays[1] = 29;
    }

    // Is the provided month is range. 
    if (month < 1 || month > 12) {
        return false;
    }
    
    // Is the day in range for the specific month
    if (day < 1 || day > maxDays[month - 1]) {
        return false;
    }
    // If everything is good we return true.
    else {
        return true;
    }
}
```

The above code assumes the date format of "MM/dd/yyyy". If however it is suppose to be a format of "dd/MM/yyyy" then where the date string is parsed, swap `m` and `d`.

I should think that you would place this method into the **Utility** class. To use this method for your particular use-case, I believe it would be:

```
if(parameterIn.get("date") != null) { 
    String dateString = (String) parameterIn.get(Constants.DATE.getValue());
    if (dateString != null && !dateString.trim().isEmpty() 
                && util.isDateStringValid(dateString)) { 
        // Whatever you want here IF date is valid...
    }
    else {
        // Whatever you want here IF the date is Invalid...
    } 
}
else {
    this.addAdvice(Constants.MGBD100005.getValue());
}
```

Comment: Welcome back!! About the programming that you put, I get a little error, you can see it in the update of my publication please! 

Look the new update.

Comment: The **new** `isDateStringValid()` method only takes one argument now, not two as you show in your examples in **Update 2**. This is my fault as I did not update how to implement this method in your Use-Case. Please see the update. You might also want to make sure the `(String) parameterIn.get(Constants.DATE.getValue())` is providing what is required'. Perhaps try: `System.out.println((String) parameterIn.get(Constants.DATE.getValue()));` to see what comes up within the console window. Put it just before the `if` statement.

Comment: Unfortunately I can't use the System.out.println, the only one I can "use" is a LOGGER.Info :(

Comment: Uhhhh, I see. I can only think of one thing at the moment just to cover another base. I would like you to try this, replace the `if` block code but keep the `else`: Use this `if` block instead: `if(parameterIn.get("date") != null) { String dateString = (String) parameterIn.get(Constants.DATE.getValue()); if (dateString != null && !dateString.trim().isEmpty() && util.isDateStringValid(dateString)) { /* Whatever you want to do here because if you made it here the data is valid */ } }`

Comment: @DevilsHnd can you check update 3, this is how I understood you that I should put it, if I'm wrong, you can tell me! Thanks a lot!

Comment: I modified your **Update 3** to what I think it should be.

Comment: @DevilsHnd I'm sorry I'm very confused, really, I can't give a single thing with this, it seems to be difficult... When I put in the local environment online (a date that does not exist, for example 02/29/2012 (LeapYear date)) I do not get returns no error value. I just remember that I have to write the date in a local online environment.

Comment: @Carlosfernando, I can't help you with that.

Answer (score 1):

Since you already have a `Utility` class, write one more utility method.  Now all you have to do is see if the day portion of your date falls in between 1 and `maxDays`.

```
public int getMaximumDays(int month, int year) {
    int[] maxDays = { 31, 28, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31 };
    if (month < 1 || month > 12) {
        return -1;
    }
    if (month == 2 && isLeapYear(year)) {
        return 29;
    } else {
        return maxDays[month - 1];
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use the lib code

```
public static boolean isLeapYear(int yr) {
  Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
  cal.set(Calendar.YEAR, yr);
  return cal.getActualMaximum(Calendar.DAY_OF_YEAR) > 365;
}
```

But if you are going to reinvent this wheel then:

```
public static boolean isLeapYear(int year) {
  if (year % 4 != 0) {
    return false;
  } else if (year % 400 == 0) {
    return true;
  } else if (year % 100 == 0) {
    return false;
  } else {
    return true;
  }
}
```

Comment: `Calendar` is not allowed according to the post.